Paired Non-parametric test with more than 3 groups but just two timepoints
I may not have found the right term to search for, so I am asking what might be a straightforward question:
Assume we have an experiment with paired non-normal distributed data, called "Pre" and "Post".



ID
Pre
Post
Subgroup




1
12
13
low


2
14
15
medium


3
16
17
high


4
18
12
low


5
14
20
medium


6
20
22
high



I would like to investigate the overall effect, which I would normally do using the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Additionally, I want to determine if there are differences within the subgroups, despite their unequal sizes. I don't intend to compare between the subgroups but rather to see if the observation is present within each subgroup, such as "low".
In this case, I could again use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test if the global value is significant, but I am concerned that this may increase the Type I error.
Some authors suggest related problems can be addressed using the Quade or Friedman test. However, these are suitable for more than two paired observations, which is not the case here.
Would an adjustment of the p-value/3 for the three subgroups according to the Bonferroni method be suitable or even necessary?
I assume there may not be a definitive answer, but I would appreciate your thoughts on this topic.
Best wishes and thanks for your help!
Edit: Clarification due to language problems.

The term "non-parametric" is not used correctly with "data" here. Being non-parametric can be a characteristic of a model or an inference method such as a test, but not of data. Do you mean "non-quantitative"/ordinal by this? Or do you rather want to say that you don't believe data are normally distributed (or according to any parametric model you know)? Note that the latter does not automatically mean that you can't use a parametric approach based on, for example, normality, as these can work well also with non-normal data (although not always, some care is needed).

Sorry, it was due to language problems. I will edit accordingly.

Without seeing your data and knowing about sample sizes, it isn't possible to say whether inference based on the normality assumption is fine here, but it may well be. This would give you access to models that capture the overall structure of your experiment. If there are meaningful differences between your subgroups, assumptions for a global signed rank test are violated as this requires i.i.d. observations.

The rank difference test is better than the signed-rank test and generalizes to allow for covariate adjustment, multiple groups, and longitudinal data through the proportional odds ordinal regression model.  See this.
